# What is the Hero's loot for?

Tags: heroville

This may be a dumb question, but I could find NOTHING for this.

In Heroville you have  loot in your hero's when they're hunting. What is this loot? Can I use it? How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Basic Explaination**

In the Options/Help tab:

- Upgrade the Tent to attract new Heroes.
- Hero will adventure and earn gold and resources from defeating monsters.
- **Gold will be used by the hero to purchase items from your town. That gold will then be transfered to the towns gold.**
- A Heroes level will increase their effectiveness while working.

This means that heroes resources and gold are to buy the items you offer (potions, weapons, accessories, ...).

**Additional Observations**

When you employ a hero to work for you, they will no longer gain experience (unless they were trained via the Academy).  The treasure chest resource, which the code refers to as `scrap` is used for repairing.  The code for that is:

```
while (weapon.durability < $scope.weapons[weapon.id].durability && hero.equip.scrap > (weapon.id - 1) && $scope.resources != $scope.maxResources) {
  hero.equip.scrap -= weapon.id;
  weapon.durability++;
  $scope.resources += weapon.id;
}
```

This means, while the weapon can be fixed, the hero has scrap >= the weapon's location in the list of weapons, and you have not hit the max for the treasure chest resource, the hero will continue repairing.

So, say your hero has a Hand Axe that lost 10 durability.  This is the 2nd weapon on the list, so each point of durability will cost 2 scrap.  If the hero has 20 scrap, they can fully repair it.  If they only have 5, they can spend 4 to get 2 points back and keep the last 1.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. So they're workers, and I have to pay them in goods to get their gold? What about the "chest" thing? How does that work? Also, when I assign the hero's to work for me and gather resources, they're acting like my slaves. I pay them nothing and they work for free. I'm still confused, I hope you can elaborate.